# Win32 Edit Controls of WS_EX_LAYERED parent dont receive mouse/click events when their background is transparent

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to put some edit fields ontop of a splash screen which is rendered in another top level window (transparent PNG similar to this http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/09/displaying_a_splash_screen_with_c_part_ii.html) .

I made a secondary window which is always on top of my splash screen, and made it also transparent with WS_EX_LAYERED.

Now i set the background color of the edit fields in the wndproc by catching WM_CTLCOLOREDIT.

This works fine, my input controls are transparent (e.g. invisible) and only the entered text is visible on the splash screen.

Now the issue comes that the mouse cursor which indicates here is a text box does not work, neither can i click in that box to have it focus. The problem all disappears if i do NOT make the background of the edit control transparent. There is also no WM_NCHITTEST when its transparent. The only time im getting a mousecursor is if there is (visible)text already entered in the box

```
g_HWNControlsParent = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_LAYERED,.....);
hwLoginField = CreateWindowEx(NULL,"EDIT", "-User-",    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_TABSTOP, ....g_HWNControlsParent);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(g_HWNControlsParent,RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY) ;
```

in HWNControlsParent wndproc

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT: { // BG Color of Input Fields
        HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(230,230,230));
        SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,0)); // Color of Background where Text is entered
         SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,0)); // Color of Background where no Text is
        return (LRESULT) GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH); // return a DC brush.
    }
```

Comment: This is by design.  Any part of the window that's transparent to the user's eye is transparent to mouse clicks as well.  They get sent to the window underneath.  You cannot change this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an alpha of 1 instead of 0 for the transparent regions, they will still be transparent but will respond to mouse clicks.

Comment: You mean SetLayeredWindowAttributes(g_HWNControlsParent,RGB(0, 0, 0), 1, LWA_COLORKEY) ;  ? This does not work either

Comment: You can't specify the alpha when using `LWA_COLORKEY`, you would need to use per-pixel alpha via `UpdateLayeredWindow`.

Comment: I tried using UpdateLayeredWindow - in that case everything was transparent - even the text in the editbox - however the correct mouse behaviour was observed - do you have an example where this works correctly?

Comment: @Steve Were you able to solve your problem? if you did, can you please post the code as a project so other can learn to. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not as intended, i added a workaround - i catched the WM_LBUTTONDOWN etc in my windowproc. And then i checked if the mousecursor is within a defined rectangle (PtInRect(&passwordEdit,g_CursorPoint)) - if thats the case i manually propagated focus (SetFocus(GetDlgItem(g_HWNLoginParent, ID_PASSWORD_EDIT)); ) - Basically i defined rectangles with coordinates/width where my input fields are and then manually check if a click would be at their positon.